# Embedding of a ring into a ring with unity

Tags: ring-theory, rngs

I was reading the theorem on *Embedding of a ring into a ring with unity* which is as follows:

> Let R be ring and $R\times \mathbb Z=\{(r,n)|r\in R,n\in \mathbb Z\}$. 
>   This is a ring with addition defined as $(r,n)+(s,m)=(r+s,n+m).$ and multiplication defined as :$(r,n).(s,m)=(rs+ns+mr,nm)$ .this ring has unity as $(0,1)$.
>
> Now we can easily show that
>   If we define an homomorphism from $R\to R_1$ as $f(r)=(r,0)$  $\forall r\in R$ then $R \cong f(R)\subseteq R_1$.
>   Hence $R$ is embedable in $R_1$ which has unity $(0,1)$.

I can't understand why in the ring $R\times \mathbb Z=\{(r,n)|r\in R,n\in \mathbb Z\}$ we had to define multiplication as $(r,n).(s,m)=(rs+ns+mr,nm)$, why can't we define it as $(r,n).(s,m)=(rs,nm)$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your multiplication, what is your proposed unity?

Comment: that is what I can't figure out does it have a unity or not..how to check please help..

Comment: @spectraa If some $(r,n)$ were a unity with respect to your multiplication, then $r$ would be a unity of $R$.

Comment: @spectraa: Being a unit is an equation: you can solve equations... or show they have no solutions.

Answer (score 3):

it may be helpful to look on the ring with unity as 
$$
eR \oplus \mathbb{Z}
$$
where $e$ is an idempotent which commutes with all other elements and satisfies  $e^2=e$

then every element is of the form $er +m$ and we have:

$$
(er+m)(es+n) = e^2rs+ern+mes +mn = e(rs+nr+ms) + mn
$$
the unity is the element $1$

Comment: It can also be viewed somewhat as both rings acting on each other.

Comment: is this the only ring with unity in which R can be embedded??

Comment: How is the multiplication of elements $n$ with $r$ and that of $m$ with $s$ defined, though? I do understand how it forms an embedding, beyond that, but would appreciate it if you could clear this point.

Answer (score 0):

Legend has it that one may construct $\mathbb Z$ from $\mathbb W:=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ by $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N / \sim$, where $(a,b)\sim (x,y)$ is defined by a+y=b+x  (meaning $b-a=y-x$ intuitively).

Next I saw similar definitions of addition and multiplication, namely

$$(a,b)(x,y) = (ay+bx, ax+by).$$

I looks a little different right? Because its background thought is

$$ (ax+by)-(ay+bx) = (b-a)(y-x).$$

So in the rIng-rng embedding case, I change the definition of multiplication by the thought (Yes, just unreasonably do it, for an idea! )

$$(m-r)(n-s)= mn - (rn+sm-rs),$$

i.e. $(r,m)(s,n):=(rn+sm-rs, mn)$. Then the mul-asso, distribution law also hold, and so does the identity and embedding property.